# Issue dump Twig with Vuejs

Tags: twig, vuejs2

I have some problem with Twig and Vuejs2 when i try to {{dump(variable)}} in my Twig template.
My dump is broken (style and tree) and i have an error in the dev tool :

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template: [...]
>   Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.

I think the problem come from the script tag appended to the DOM due to dump.

How can i fix the dump (style and tree) ?

I need some help please.